# Accurate color quantization of image to minimize color palette

Tags: python, image, image-processing, colors, quantization

I'm trying to quantize an image keeping all primary colors in place and removing all minor colors such as "anti-aliasing" borders.
E.g. the image below ultimately should be quantized to 3 colors whereas the number of actual colors in the original image is more than 30. All "anti-aliasing" border colors should be considered minors and eliminated upon quantization as well as "jpeg artifacts", which add more colors to the image because of over-optimization.
Note: a source image could be either png or jpeg.

[image: 3 color example]

For the quantization itself, I'm using `PIL.quantize(...)` with K as the number of colors to leave. And it works fairly well and keeps the palette perfectly matching to the original.

```
def color_quantize(path, K):
    image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))
    im_pil = im_pil.quantize(K, None, 0, None)
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im_pil.convert("RGB")), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Thus, if I knew "K" (the number of primary colors) in advance, then I would use it for `im_pil.quantize(...)`. Basically, I need a way to get that "K" number.
Is there any way to determine the number of primary colors?

BTW, regarding the "jpeg artifacts" removal, I'm using `img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 75, 75)` at the moment, which works quite well.

Comment: Quantization is basically a clustering technique. There are clustering methods that don’t need a parameter *k*, they find a “natural” set of clusters. For example DBSCAN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to analyze the histograms of the RGB channels to find out how many peaks they have, hopefully you will have a few big peaks, and some very small ones, then the number of big peaks should be your K.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the following function to determine the number for dominant colors:

```
def get_dominant_color_number(img, threshold):
    # remove significant artifacts
    img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 75, 75) 

    # resize image to make the process more efficient on 250x250 (without antialiasing to reduce color space)
    thumbnail = cv2.resize(img, (250, 250), None)

    # convert to HSV color space 
    imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(thumbnail, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV).astype("float32")
    (h, s, v) = cv2.split(imghsv)

    # quantize saturation and value to merge close colors
    v = (v // 30) * 30
    s = (s // 30) * 30

    imghsv = cv2.merge([h,s,v])
    thumbnail = cv2.cvtColor(imghsv.astype("uint8"), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    (unique, counts) = np.unique(thumbnail.reshape(-1, thumbnail.shape[2]), return_counts=True, axis = 0)

    # calculate frequence of each color and sort them 
    freq = counts.astype("float")
    freq /= freq.sum()
    count_sort_ind = np.argsort(-counts)
    
    # get frequent colors above the specified threshold
    n = 0
    dominant_colors = []
    
    for (c) in count_sort_ind:
        n += 1;
        dominant_colors.append(unique[c])
        if (freq[c] <= threshold):
           break

    return (dominant_colors, n)

# -----------------------------------------------------------

img = cv2.imread("File.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
channels = img.shape[2]
if channels == 4:
   trans_mask = img[:,:,3] == 0
   img[trans_mask] = [254, 253, 254, 255]
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

(dom_colors, dom_color_num) = get_dominant_color_number(img, .0045)
```

For the threshold ".0045" it gives an acceptable result. Yet, it still looks a bit "artificial".